# Comparing 2 attributes with shared ID from 2 different nodes and bring back other attributes

Tags: xml, xpath

is there a way to search an id shared between two nodes with different attribute name and response back the third attribute.

in the XML below I would like to have the following logic:
for `//schedules/tttr/@12345` search for the value in p attribute (in that case 1569735)
Search the p attribute value (1569735) in all `programs/p/@id` attributes.
if match, bring `//programs/p/@t` (in that case 'Prime Discussion')

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <schedules>
        <tttr 12345 
        <s s="2019-09-18T00:00:00" d="1800" p="1569735" c="100007">
            <f id="3" />
        </s>
    </schedules>
    <programs>
        <p id="1569735" t="Prime Discussion" d="Discussion on Current Affairs." rd="Discussion on Current Affairs." l="en">
            <f id="2" />
            <f id="21" />
            <k id="6" v="20160614" />
            <k id="1" v="2450548" />
            <k id="18" v="12983658" />
            <k id="21" v="12983658" />
            <k id="10" v="Program" />
            <k id="19" v="SH024505480000" />
            <k id="20" v="http://tmsimg.com/assets/p12983658_b_h5_aa.jpg" />
            <c id="607" />
        </p>
    </programs>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to find the value `Prime Discussion` is this:

```
/root/programs/p[@id = /root/schedules/tttr/s/@p]/@t
```

If you want to look globally for the elements, you can also use

```
//programs/p[@id = //schedules/tttr/s/@p]/@t
```

**Result is:**

```
Prime Discussion
```

**P.S.:** The above lines assume that the XML is *well-formed* and looks like this (`12345` was removed and a closing tag added):

```
...
<schedules>
    <tttr>
      <s s="2019-09-18T00:00:00" d="1800" p="1569735" c="100007">
        <f id="3" />
      </s>
    </tttr>
</schedules>
....
```

Comment: @RonenNoimark: It is a custom on SO to accept a helpful answer. Take [_the Tour_](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn about questions and answers (and accepting them) and earn the `Informed` badge.